# Is it possible to cheat C# compiler to box Nullable<T> struct ant not its value?

Tags: c#, nullable

Well, the question may seem odd. And it really is.
Yet I strongly believe that such hacks help in understanding the language and .net platform.

It is how C# compiler treats nullable types implies this question.

`Nullable<T>` is a struct. But compiler boxes not this struct but the value it holds or just null reference.

It is also intersting how unboxing will work in the case of the boxed Nullable.

```
Nullable<int> myInt = boxedStruct as Nullable<int>;
```

here I meen that `boxedStruct` is not a boxed int but the whole struct.

Well, may be Nullables are treated differently at CLR level because I cannot understand the ouptut of the program below.

```
class Program
{
    public static bool? Property { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Property = true;

        var valueType = typeof (Program).GetProperty("Property").GetValue(null).GetType();
        var propType = typeof (Program).GetProperty("Property").PropertyType;

        Console.WriteLine("Value's type '{0}' is the same as type of the property '{1}' - '{2}'", valueType, propType, valueType == propType);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output:

> Value's type 'System.Boolean' is the same as type of the property
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]' - 'False'

**Update:**

Here what specification (ECMA 335) says:

> I.8.2.4 Boxing and unboxing of values
>  ...
>  If the value type
>   is a nullable type—defined as an instantiation of the value type
>   System.Nullable—the result is a null reference or bitwise copy of
>   its Value property of type T, depending on its HasValue property
>   (false and true, respectively).

So if I understand this correctly. `Nullable<T>` strcut cannot be boxed in .Net Framework and it's not just impossible with C# compiler but with CLR as well.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? I don't really understand what you're up to.

Comment: You should show an example in your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I can't figure out what question you're asking here.

Comment: Through C# code, I highly doubt it.  Writing IL code directly, most probably.

Comment: @EricLippert "Can you box a `Nullable<int>` value without having it being translated to a boxed `null` value or a boxed `int` value?"

Comment: @voroninp: Do you have any reason to *want* to do this?

Comment: @Brain No practical reasons.

Comment: @Servy Boxing is done with the ``box valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<...>`` instruction. It is the same for any value type.

Comment: I wanted to know the same thing as I have general conversions from "object" to other types, e.g. DateTime, and needed to know if I have to handle the case where the object might be DateTime?. If it is not possible to box a nullable then I do not have to cater for DateTime? -just null and DateTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am conjecturing that the question you are trying to ask is:

> Can you box a `Nullable<int>` value without producing a null reference or a boxed int value, but instead an actually boxed `Nullable<int>`?

No.

Comment: Yes. Well, I think I should better learn English to express ideas less vague.

Comment: I think the OP wants an instance of type `object{int?}`. It seems to be implicitly converted from `int?` to `int` when boxed though. Hence the need for *cheating*.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to cheat C# compiler to box `Nullable<T>`?

No, as it is not the compiler who does the boxing, it is the CLR. Yes, the boxing of nullable types is specifically handled in the CLR itself.

So is there a way to box a nullable struct without this special handling? Also no.

But it is possible to box another structure that looks like `Nullable<T>` (ensuring it has the appropriate layout) and with the help of undocumented keywords and memory hacking trick the CLR into thinking the boxed object is actually of `Nullable<T>`.
**Beware!** This code should be used only for educational purposes. I can't guarantee it will work on other platforms or work at all in different conditions, because it relies on the underlying layout of managed objects.

```
public static unsafe object BoxNullable<T>(T? nullable) where T : struct
{
    object scam = new NullableFake<T>(nullable);
    TypedReference tr = __makeref(scam);
    IntPtr typehandle = typeof(Nullable<T>).TypeHandle.Value;
    IntPtr* trstruct = (IntPtr*)&tr;
    **((IntPtr**)trstruct[0]) = typehandle;
    return scam;
}

struct NullableFake<T> where T : struct
{
    public readonly T? Value;

    public NullableContainer(T? nullable)
    {
        Value = nullable;
    }
}
```

The `NullableFake<T>` structure has the same layout as `Nullable<T>`, so it is safe to use it for boxing. `TypedReference` is used for obtaining a pointer to the variable (that contains a pointer to the object), exposing the object itself. The first value in the object's memory layout is a pointer to the object's type. Overwriting it results in the CLR thinking the type is different.

I don't know any safer way to do it.